# wireless point-to-point security

Tags: wireless

I have a remote site where I need to bridge approx 700m distance either with fibre or wireless for a backbone internet connection.

The digging would cost a bit more and many suppliers are offering point-to-point wireless technology.

I have seen Ubiquity, Silku and Cisco Meraki and I am sure there are many others which I am not aware of.

Price is one factor which I would only look at if you can compare apples to apples.

My question is about the security of Point-to-Point wireless. Could you help me gather some security criteria to help to decide what technology would suit the best for this scenario?

I am trying to not be biased towards any brands but instead focusing on the security elements.

Answer (score 1):

In short: wireless means data travel through the air and can thus easily be sniffed. This means you need some protection against sniffing and this is commonly done using encryption. There are established encryption methods for wireless networks (see [Wikipedia:Wi-Fi Protected Access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access)
 for details). If these are not implemented or not deemed sufficient it is also possible to run a VPN like IPSec on top of the wireless connection.

Another issue to look out for is that the devices by themselves don't have any backdoors or security problem which might be used as a backdoor. Because otherwise some attacker might reconfigure the device or get access to the encryption keys and thus can decrypt sniffed data. Running a VPN on top of the wireless connection and independently from the devices providing the connection can mitigate this issue since it is now not enough to crack the encryption of the wireless layer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it makes sense. Would you be kind to outline some good practice for this backbone scenario that should be implemented or available as a feature?

Comment: @AndrasSebestyen: I'm not sure what good practice you image. The good practice is to use known secure technologies (i.e. encryption with integrity protection and also authentication of the endpoints) and I've mentioned the main ones related to your question in my answer. The details then depend on the specific technology and products you want to use.

Comment: thank you for your help.  I will endeavour those options and will match what supplier offer on the security side as well.